# Fixing an npm package with a missing file

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Until recently, it was impossible to create a file called "important.js" on my PC, due to it being blocked as possible ransomware. Unfortunately, quite a few libraries in the node.js universe want to create a file with this name. Consequently, I have some npm installations that are broken. In particular, I am missing this file from the stylehacks package in a webpack application.

I can't find any way of fixing the missing file. I tried just creating it manually and pasting the correct code from github into it, but the build process says the code is wrong. I tried running `npm uninstall stylehacks` with the intention of running the install command again, but nothing seemed to happen - the package wasn't removed. The package isn't listed in the package.json file, so I assume it's a dependency of webpack or possibly babel.

Is there any way I can fix this missing file?

Comment: That's very odd... what version of Windows are you using? I can create a file named `important.js` with no issues.

Comment: What version of NPM?  Older versions of NPM used to attempt very long path names which became invalid really quick.  Babel was always an offender.

Comment: Files named "important.js" were getting blocked by McAfee on my PC. As I noted, this was due to a perception that they were associated with ransomware. I spoke to the Support people and they agreed to unblock it.

Answer (score 0):

I just got an email warning of malware in a particular npm package. The fix was to delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again. I suppose that will work for me.